# JavaScript Regex for character limit without whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am rusty on regex and getting stuck one something that should be simple.
I need to limit an input string to a minimum of 1 and a max of 50 characters (inclusive). This bit works: `^.{1,50}$`. I then also need to prevent any of the inout value to be a whitespace, so if someone entered 1+ whitespaces, this should be rejected. I tried doing a negative lookup to prevent whitespace, but this is where things go wrong. This bit does not seem to work.

```
var myRe = new RegExp('^.{1,50}(?!.*\s)*$', 'g');
```

[image]

Help would be greatly appreciated. Totally stumped on this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to allow whitespaces only for the whole inout value, you can assert at least a single non whitespace char.

```
^(?=\s*\S).{1,50}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6qaG4u/1)

For example

```
var myRe = /^(?=\s*\S).{1,50}$/g;
```

[image]

---

Or using a negative lookahead

```
^(?!\s*$).{1,50}$
```

[Rgex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v7eK54/1)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just match only non-whitespace characters:

```
var myRe = new RegExp('^\\S{1,50}$', 'g');
```

By the way, your negative lookahead approach can be made to work by putting the lookahead at the start of the pattern:

```
var myRe = new RegExp('^(?!.*\\s).{1,50}$', 'g');
```

Note that `\\s` and `\\S` require double escaping when using the `RegExp` object.